# Launch a codeblock in "screen"

Tags: bash, ssh, scripts, screen, wget

I'm working on a script that downloads large files like installers, youtube video series or torrents. It's supposed to work on a Raspbian. So the main part has to be delt with in a screen session. Or else the user would have to keep the ssh connection active all the time.

It's also supposed to get it's input from a textfile containing multiple entries like:

```
http://youtube.com/BlaBla video ~/Videos
http://vlc-project.org/downloads/BlaBla file ~/Downloads
BlaBla.torrent torrent ~/Downloads
```

So the codeblock would be something like:

```
while read -r line; do
  # Code for simple file
  # Code for Video
  # Code for torrent
done < "$inputFile"
```

How do I execute the entire while loop in a screen session? Is this even possible?

Greetings and thanks in advance

Markus

Comment: Same way you do anything in screen; run `screen`, then run the command.

Answer (score 1):

Screen man page mentions the following syntax:

> screen [ -options ] [ cmd [ args ] ]

And this:

> In addition, new windows can be created by running a command like:
>
> ```
>           screen emacs prog.c
> ```
>
> from  a  shell prompt within a previously created window.  This will not run another copy of screen, but will
>          instead supply the command name and its arguments to the window manager (specified in  the  $STY  environment
>          variable)  who will use it to create the new window

So put your codeblock into a script , and launch from a terminal it like so

```
screen myScript.sh
```